# Removing the first and last character of a string C#

Tags: c#

For an exercise on codewars I had to remove the first and last character of a string. After some fidling about I found a solution that works:

```
    public static string Remove_char(string s)
    {
      return s.Substring(1, s.Length - 2);   
    }
```

My question is why do I have to use -2 instead of -1 at the end of the return line when I only want to remove the last character?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the second parameter isn't the *offset* upto which you want the substring, it is the *length* of the desired substring.

Answer (score 1):

The Substring counts the length starting at the first index.

So if you remove the first character the string already has `s.Length-1`. If you now want to remove the last character as well you need to use `s.Length-2`.

Answer (score 0):

the array index start from 0 and if you jump to last index then you need to s.Length-1 i.e length of array - 1. So your problem is you need to remove last character that why you added s.Length-2

Answer (score 0):

Because you want to return a substring from the second up to the second to last character of the initial string i.e. **not** the first (0th character) and **not** the last (length-1 character).